# How to monitor a windows service (not just default status but to check whether it is WORKING (working on a database table or not))

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-services

Background: I have a developed a windows service which run every day at 12pm (calls an so and do its work).

Now I have a web application - one of its operation is "**To call an sp and regenerate the data**" (the sp is the same one which windows service is calling) **So, I have to make sure before calling that sp from web application that the windows service has not called the sp at that time or is not working on that db table** .. other wise there would be some consequences..

How can I achieve this thing?
Your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Implement proper locking in the database. Either using table / row locks or using a custom locked objects table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, having a stored proc that can only be called by a single client at any time might be a bad thing - suggests your transaction management may be suspect.

However, there are legitimate reasons for doing this - e.g. if the stored proc consumes a lot of system resources.

I've done this by creating a "batches" table, roughly as follows:

```
batchid   start_date    end_date   current_status
```

When the proc starts, it inserts a record in this table with a NULL end date and "Started" current_status; when it completes, it updates that record with end_date and "finished" current_status.

You can then insert a check at the start of the proc and have it return immediately if it finds a record in the "batches" table with a current_status of "started".

You have to make sure all exit points from the proc update the current_status field - otherwise your proc will never run after an error causes the proc to abort.

Ugly, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at wrapping the work inside this stored proc in calls to [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx).

On the other hand, it's generally better to eliminate whatever is requiring you to serialize access to the procedure.

---

E.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doStuff
AS
    DECLARE @rc int;
    EXEC @rc = sp_getapplock 'doStuff','Exclusive','Session';

    IF @rc < 0 return;

    --Do interesting things

    EXEC sp_releaseapplock 'doStuff', 'Session'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Will you please elaborate the snippet, What is this Exclusive and Session? and do I have to make a new suporting stored procedure for that or just add these locking statements to the main sp..

Comment: @Sailaziz - I'd add these into the existing stored proc. Where I mention these procedures in the first paragraph, I link to the MSDN documentation for them. Exclusive means that no-one else can get the same lock. Session means the lock is held until a) sp_releaseapplock is called, or b) the connection that acquired the lock is closed.

Comment: is there any other way around to figure this thing? can i check the status of windows service at that instant of time or something else.. I don't want to bound things on db as my sp consist on huge number of lines (so much processing) and there are 4 of these - which mean four lock and then i also need to synchronize those - much overhead and performance go down.. Please suggest the other better way out. Thanks again!

Comment: @Sailaziz - but from your description, the resource(s) you're trying to "protect" are in the database. Checking the status of a service is going to be unreliable - between determining the status, and starting your own activity, the status may have changed and you'll have a conflict.